# Compare if textfield value is greater then x

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I compare a numeric value in a textfield against any given value x?
Iam writing the code in TSQL.

See code below:

```
DECLARE @TA_SM varchar(5000)
DECLARE @TA_MSD varchar(5000)
DECLARE @T_SUM  int(5)

SET @TA_SM = '[field name='Toelichting_advies_ISM']'
SET @TA_MSD = '[field name='Toelichting_advies_MSD']'
SET @T_SUM = '[field name='Offerte_totaalsom']'

IF ((@TA_SM = '') OR (@TA_MSD = '')) AND (@T_SUM >25.000)
    SELECT 1
ELSE
    SELECT 2
```

I get a error message saying:

> Must declare the table value @T_SUM

The statement before the AND operator is working just fine.

Comment: Iam working in a webform builder environment.

Comment: @IvannickdeFreijtas Could you please provide some real values ?

Comment: @IvannickdeFreijtas You are assigning  `[field name='Offerte_totaalsom']` to SET @T_SUM how you even get the error you said in your question ? Please post the full code.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `DECLARE @T_SUM int(5)` to `DECLARE @T_SUM int`.
If you only want to have 5 digits use `NUMERIC` instead of `INT`.

EDIT 1 - Full code.

This should run through in TSQL without error but I am not sure if this is the result you are looking for.  I have added extra quote marks to your variables definitions.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @TA_SM varchar(5000)
DECLARE @TA_MSD varchar(5000)
DECLARE @T_SUM int

SET @TA_SM = '[field name=''Toelichting_advies_ISM'']'

SET @TA_MSD = '[field name=''Toelichting_advies_MSD'']'

SET @T_SUM = '[field name=''Offerte_totaalsom'']'

IF ((@TA_SM = '') OR (@TA_MSD = '')) AND (@T_SUM >25.000)

SELECT 1

ELSE

SELECT 2
END
```

Comment: Tried both options, but I still get the same error message

Comment: I pasted the code above with a correction for the variable definitions.

Comment: At first the webform seemed to disappear. Tried it again and basically got the same error code. Maybe it could have something to do with it recognizing the input as a string instead of a integer? Do I have to CAST it perhaps?

Comment: Yes I think that is the problem.  You are basically putting a string into your variables and I think you want the value of the field named in the string.  So casting would not work if I understand your requirement correctly.  You need to read the field values and store these in the variables.  So you should be doing a SELECT from a table somewhere to populate these variables.

Comment: I managed to write the input to the underlying database but  now I get another error message. But I suppose that is beyond this scope. Ill will submit another question if I will be unable to solve. Nevertheless thanks for the thought process!